# Difference between spark Vectors and scala immutable Vector?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am writing a project for Spark 1.4 in Scala and am currently in between converting my initial input data into `spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors` and `scala.immutable.Vector` that I later want to work with in my algorithm. Could someone briefly explain the difference between the two and in what situation one would be more useful to use than the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` is designed for linear algebra applications.  `mllib` provides two different implementations - `DenseVector`, `SparseVector`. While you have access to useful methods like `norm` or `sqdist` it is rather limited otherwise.

As all data structures from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg` it can store only 64-bit floating point numbers (`scala.Double`).

If you plan to use `mllib` then `spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` is pretty much your only option. All the remaining data structures from `mllib`, both local and distributed, are build on top of `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`.

Otherwise, `scala.immutable.Vector` is probably a much better choice. It is a general purpose, dense data structure.

It can store objects of any type, so you can have `Vector[String]` for example.

Since it is `Traversable` you have access to all expected methods like `map`, `flatMap`, `reduce`, `fold`, `filter`, etc.

**Edit**: If you need algebraic operations and don't use any of the data structures from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed` you may prefer `breeze.linalg.Vector` over `spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`. It supports larger set of the algebraic methods including `dot` product and provides typical collection API.

Comment: @zero323 cool comment deleted so now only the NSA knows and I'll delete this comment soon as well :)