# create a new accumulator and vector addition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am following the [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions)  but encountering some problems with `accumulator` and `Vector`

I have the following object defining the `VectorAccumulatorParam`:

```
object VectorAccumulatorParam extends AccumulatorParam[Vector] {
    def zeros(initialValue: Vector): Vector = {
        Vectors.zeros( initialValue.size )
    }
    def addInPlace(v1: Vector, v2: Vector): Vector = {
        v1 += v2
    }
}
```

It is used like:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

object SimpleSpark {
    def main(arg: Array[String]) = {
        /* some coed */

        val valAccum = sc.accumulator( Vector(1, 2, 3) )(VectorAccumulatorParam) 

        /* some coed */
}
```

But I got two errors:

```
[error] /home/cliu/Documents/github/Apache-Spark/src/main/scala/SimpleSpark.scala:125: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : VectorAccumulatorParam.type
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.AccumulatorParam[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]]
[error]         val valAccum = sc.accumulator( Vector(1, 2, 3) )(VectorAccumulatorParam) 
[error]                                                          ^
[error] /home/cliu/Documents/github/Apache-Spark/src/main/scala/SimpleSpark.scala:170: value += is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
[error]         v1 += v2
[error]            ^
```

First: Why there is a type mismatch? It is what is written in the programming guide. And it should return a `Vector`.

Second: Why the guide is like this if the operation `v1 += v2` is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You get a type error because `Vector(1, 2, 3)` creates `scala.collection.immutable.Vector`, which is immutable equivalent of the `Array`, not `mllib.linalg.Vector`. `mllib.linalg.Vectors` don't provide companion objects
2. As already stated by [Alberto Bonsanto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689706/alberto-bonsanto) `mllib.linalg.Vectors` don't support addition operation.
3. There is also a typo in the param definition. The correct name of the method is `zero` not `zeros`.
4. Regarding the programming guide I guess you've missed following statement:

   > supposing we had a Vector class representing mathematical vectors, we could write

You could create an accumulator using `breeze.linalg.Vector`:

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV}

object VectorAccumulatorParam extends AccumulatorParam[BDV[Double]] {
  def zero(v: BDV[Double]): BDV[Double] = v
  def addInPlace(v1: BDV[Double], v2: BDV[Double]): BDV[Double] = v1 += v2
}

val valAccum = sc.accumulator(BDV.zeros[Double](3))(VectorAccumulatorParam)
```

See also: [Difference between spark Vectors and scala immutable Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31255756/1560062)

Comment: what is the difference between `DenseVector`, `Vector` and `Vectors`?

Answer (score 1):

The second one first, because it is easier.
If you read the documentation of [Vector](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) you will realize that they don't have the `+=` method, therefore the concatenation you want to achieve can't be done this way, nevertheless some other classes support that method, take a look on [Accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Accumulator), so my suggestion is to write your own method to achieve this.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by _they do have support for that_?